# awk - I can't print to file

Tags: awk

I don't know ,why I can't print from to file. My command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "af">file}'
```

Error:

```
fatal: expression for `>>' redirection has null string value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`file` needs to be in quotes else awk will attempt to parse `file` as a variable rather than a string:

```
 awk 'BEGIN{print "af">"file"}'
```

Comment: ... or else `file` has to be assigned a value: `awk 'BEGIN {file="mytest"; print "af">file}'`.